# Should interactive-fiction/visual-novels/gamebooks be considered on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

For those who aren't familiar, titles like Steve Jackson and Ian Livingstone's [Fighting Fantasy](http://officialfightingfantasy.blogspot.co.uk/p/what-is-fighting-fantasy.html) series of interactive fiction or video games like [VA-11 Hall-A](http://store.steampowered.com/app/447530/).

There's plenty of similar interactive-fiction out there, some really though provoking and extremely well written.

The distinction here is that these are games where the *story* is front and center, and not so much the player's actions. The player just moves the story along, sometimes having an effect on the path or outcome.

Other examples of video games would be [Out There Chronicles](http://chronicles.outtheregame.com/), [Hotel Dusk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotel_Dusk:_Room_215), [Steins Gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steins;Gate), etc...

More traditional media examples would include Choose Your Own Adventure books, [Tales of the Arabian Knights](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/34119/tales-arabian-nights), and [The Extraordinary Adventures of Baron Munchausen](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2470/extraordinary-adventures-baron-munchausen).

Here's some Wikipedia pages on the different formats:

[Interactive Fiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_fiction)
[Visual Novels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_novel)
[Gamebooks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamebook)

Comment: Would this be like *Goosebumps* as well?

Comment: Strangely enough I've never read Goosebumps, so I couldn't say.

Comment: Or like the game part of The 39 Clues? It's a book series and a game.

Comment: I think any trans-media should be.

Comment: You mean like Choose Your Own Adventure stories?

Comment: I honestly don't really know what these are.  if they're a video game then I'd say no.

Comment: Choose Your Own Adventure is a type of interactive-fiction.

Comment: @DForck42 - Do some research and you'll see what I'm talking about. I'm talking about both physical interactive-fiction *and* digital.

Comment: @rkalajian there just seems to be confusion as to what you're really talking about.  "choose your own adventure" books and other written media would seem on-topic, but a video game doesn't seem on-topic to me

Comment: They're basically books but with more advanced illustrations.

Comment: Do we have any questions about these mediums yet?

Comment: Not that I've seen. I just wanted to make sure we set some kind of precedent before it comes up. I'm sure I may have a Q or two eventually.

Comment: If it helps - Arqade takes VN questions, and other video game questions. So you'd be doubling up in that regard.

Comment: @Ash - That's like saying that we shouldn't ask Sci-Fi/Fantasy questions here because we'd be doubling up on SFF.

Comment: I'm not saying don't do it, but I am also pointing out that they do have another place that if they can't be asked about here, that they can go.

Comment: @Ash We can also flag for migration.

Comment: Another meta question without any precedent bringing up that problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question doesn't tackle an existing problem. Let's not anticipate not existing problems without a single example ***question*** associated with it.

Comment: Just because we don't already have a question doesn't make it off-topic. If anything, discussion here could provoke people who are hesitant to post a question to actually post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to play devils' advocate here. I'm not sure I believe my own argument, but it's one that I think is important to, at minimum, meaningfully represent.

Literature was given the broadest possible scope at the outset, and it's our job to discover its boundaries. The default Tour really captures this:

> Literature Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for scholars and enthusiasts of literature.

The problem is, literary questions arise in many, *many* mediums beyond just books. "Literature" as a field has never been limited to just books - movies, video games, you-name-it have all been able to fall under literary critique.

A question about how [Oxenfree](http://store.steampowered.com/app/388880/) constructs its horror is totally a valid literary question, because the content being analyzed presents a narrative that's intended to be meaningful. A question about how [Fight Club](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fight_Club) (the movie) looks at self-imposed harm even in the face of great efforts to escape it would still be on-topic here, because it's a question about how elements of a story come together to present a point or argument, *either* visual *or* verbal.

I'm reluctant to cut off any media as "not literature" when, quite clearly, there's much more to the presentation of meaningful cultural discourse than books.

So, maybe in that sense, the best way to limit this might be broadly (and obviously, this would take some refinement) by whether it tries to present a narrative - whether it *has a text at all*. If it does, then maybe we shouldn't be so quick to remove it from the site.

I'm not saying we have to universally allow everything that has a text, and obviously it would take some refinement, but I think we'd be wrong, and it would be limiting, to preclude other forms of media that present equally valid and meaningful narratives and points.

Comment: I am not sure I agree with that either, but we could test it. I have upvoted it.

Comment: I really like this. Upvoted. I'm going to wait until the discussion has fulled run it's course before choosing an answer, but this will likely be it.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're suggesting. Are you suggesting that questions about movies are on-topic?

Comment: @TheBitByte Like I say, this is a devil's advocate answer. I do think, though, that it's deceptively difficult to argue that they're _off_-topic, in any way beyond "it doesn't feel right."

Answer (score 4):

Edge cases shouldn't be determined until we're staring at 'em. When we get a question about this kind of medium, it may be very obvious that it's on topic or not, and if we've already decided about it sight unseen that'll be sort of awkward.

Let our scope definition emerge incrementally experience, one meta at a time as we encounter each instance in the wild. That's what Stack policy handling is best at, and it works very well.

Answer (score 1):

A question about choose-your-own-adventure and interactive fiction that are told in the form of a story employing common literary devices are on-topic if the question about them would be on-topic otherwise. However, traditional video games even if they are plot-driven and surrounding the story are not on-topic.